# Entrada de datos mediante std::getline no espera a que el usuario ingrese la cadena

Tags: c++, string, stdin

Trato de hacer un programa en C++ para almacenar, buscar y reemplazar datos de alumnos, pero en el `case 3` (para reemplazar datos) tengo problemas con la entrada de datos tipo string.

Ya que en la parte donde el usuario debe ingresar el dato que reemplazara el antiguo nombre o apellido, **el programa no espera la entrada de datos**:

```
cout << "Dame el nombre" << endl;
getline(cin,nombre);
cout << "Dame el apellido" << endl;
getline(cin,apellido);
```

Aquí el código completo:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef struct
{
    string nombre;
    string apellido;
    int edad;
    float estatura;
    bool activo;
}Datos;



int main()
{
    int noAlumnos=2;
    Datos Alumnos[noAlumnos];
    string nombrex,aux,apellidox,aix;
    int aox,edadx;
    float apx,estaturax;
    bool activox,aax;
    int opc,td;
    bool arregloLleno=false;
    do{
    cout << " MENU " << endl;
    cout << "0 Salir" << endl;
    cout << "1 Llenar arreglo" << endl;
    cout << "2 Buscar elemento por posicion" << endl;
    cout << "3 Reemplazar elemento por posicion" << endl;
    cout << "Elije una opcion: ";
    cin >> opc;
    cin.get();
    switch(opc)
    {
 case 0:
        break;
 case 1:
        if(arregloLleno==false)
            {
                int i,edad;
                float estatura;
                char activo;
                string nombre;
                string apellido;
                for(i=0;i<noAlumnos;i++)
                    {
                        cout << "Datos del alumno " << i+1 << endl;
                        cout << "Dame el nombre" << endl;
                        getline(cin,nombre);
                        cout << "Dame el apellido" << endl;
                        getline(cin,apellido);
                        cout << "Dame la edad" << endl;
                        cin >> edad;
                        cout << "Dame la estatura" << endl;
                        cin >> estatura;
                        cin.get();
                        cout << "El alumno esta activo? (S/N)" << endl;
                        cin >> activo;
                        if((activo=='s')||(activo=='S'))
                            {
                                Alumnos[i].activo=true;
                            }
                        else
                            {
                                Alumnos[i].activo=false;
                            }
                        cin.get();
                        Alumnos[i].nombre = nombre;
                        Alumnos[i].apellido = apellido;
                        Alumnos[i].edad = edad;
                        Alumnos[i].estatura = estatura;
                    }
            arregloLleno=true;
            }
        else
            {
                cout << "Al arreglo ya se han asignado valores" << endl;
            }
        break;
case 2:
    if(arregloLleno)
        {
            int posicion=0;
            cout << "Dame la posicion del arreglo a buscar: " << endl;
            cin >> posicion;
            if(posicion>0 && posicion<=noAlumnos)
                {
                    cout << "En la posicion del arreglo " << posicion << " se encuentra los datos: " << endl;
                    cout << "Datos del alumno " << posicion << endl;
                    posicion--;
                    cout << "Nombre: " <<  Alumnos[posicion].nombre << endl;
                    cout << "Apellido: " << Alumnos[posicion].apellido << endl;
                    cout << "Edad: " << Alumnos[posicion].edad << endl;
                    cout << "Estatura: " << Alumnos[posicion].estatura << endl;
                    if(Alumnos[posicion].activo)
                        {
                            cout << "El alumno se encuentra activo" << endl;
                        }
                    else
                        {
                            cout << "El alumno no encuentra activo" << endl;
                        }
                    cout << endl;
                }
            else
                {
                    cout << "Posicion inexistente" << endl;
                }
            cin.get();
        }
        else
            {
                cout << "El arreglo no contiene valores" << endl;
            }
    break;
case 3:
    if(arregloLleno)
        {
            int posicion=0;
            cout << "Dame la posicion del arreglo a buscar: " << endl;
            cin >> posicion;
            if(posicion>0 && posicion<=noAlumnos)
                {
                    cout << "En la posicion del arreglo " << posicion << " se encuentra los datos: " << endl;
                    cout << "Datos del alumno " << posicion << endl;
                    posicion--;
                    cout << "Nombre: " <<  Alumnos[posicion].nombre << endl;
                    cout << "Apellido: " << Alumnos[posicion].apellido << endl;
                    cout << "Edad: " << Alumnos[posicion].edad << endl;
                    cout << "Estatura: " << Alumnos[posicion].estatura << endl;
                    if(Alumnos[posicion].activo)
                        {
                            cout << "El alumno se encuentra activo" << endl;
                        }
                    else
                        {
                            cout << "El alumno no encuentra activo" << endl;
                        }
                    cout << endl;
                    float estatura;
                    char activo;
                    string nombre,apellido;
                    int opcx, edad;
                    cout << "Alumno: " << posicion+1 << endl;
                    cout << "Que valor(es) deseas modificar?" << endl;
                    cout << "1 Modificar todos los elementos " << endl;
                    cout << "2 Modificar el nombre " << endl;
                    cout << "3 Modificar el apellido" << endl;
                    cout << "4 Modificar la edad " << endl;
                    cout << "5 Modificar la estatura " << endl;
                    cout << "6 Modificar el status " << endl;
                    cin >> opcx;
                    switch(opcx)
                    {
                    case 1:
                        cout << "Dame el nombre" << endl;
                        getline(cin,nombre);
                        cout << "Dame el apellido" << endl;
                        getline(cin,apellido);
                        cout << "Dame la edad" << endl;
                        cin >> edad;
                        cout << "Dame la estatura" << endl;
                        cin >> estatura;
                        cin.get();
                        cout << "El alumno esta activo? (S/N)" << endl;
                        cin >> activo;
                        if((activo=='s')||(activo=='S'))
                            {
                                Alumnos[posicion].activo=true;
                            }
                        else
                            {
                                Alumnos[posicion].activo=false;
                            }
                        cin.get();
                        Alumnos[posicion].nombre = nombre;
                        Alumnos[posicion].apellido = apellido;
                        Alumnos[posicion].edad = edad;
                        Alumnos[posicion].estatura = estatura;
                        cout << "Ahora los datos son " << endl;
                        cout << "Datos del alumno " << posicion << endl;
                        cout << "Nombre: " <<  Alumnos[posicion].nombre << endl;
                        cout << "Apellido: " << Alumnos[posicion].apellido << endl;
                        cout << "Edad: " << Alumnos[posicion].edad << endl;
                        cout << "Estatura: " << Alumnos[posicion].estatura << endl;
                        if(Alumnos[posicion].activo)
                            {
                                cout << "El alumno se encuentra activo" << endl;
                            }
                        else
                            {
                                cout << "El alumno no encuentra activo" << endl;
                            }
                        cout << endl;
                    break;
                    case 2:
                        cout << "Dame el nombre " << endl;
                        getline(cin,nombre);
                        Alumnos[posicion].nombre = nombre;
                        cout << "Ahora los datos son " << endl;
                        cout << "Datos del alumno " << posicion << endl;
                        cout << "Nombre: " <<  Alumnos[posicion].nombre << endl;
                        cout << "Apellido: " << Alumnos[posicion].apellido << endl;
                        cout << "Edad: " << Alumnos[posicion].edad << endl;
                        cout << "Estatura: " << Alumnos[posicion].estatura << endl;
                        if(Alumnos[posicion].activo)
                            {
                                cout << "El alumno se encuentra activo " << endl;
                            }
                        else
                            {
                                cout << "El alumno no encuentra activo " << endl;
                            }
                        cout << endl;
                    break;
                    case 3:
                        cout << "Dame el apellido " << endl;
                        getline(cin,apellido);
                        Alumnos[posicion].apellido = apellido;
                        cout << "Ahora los datos son " << endl;
                        cout << "Datos del alumno " << posicion << endl;
                        cout << "Nombre: " <<  Alumnos[posicion].nombre << endl;
                        cout << "Apellido: " << Alumnos[posicion].apellido << endl;
                        cout << "Edad: " << Alumnos[posicion].edad << endl;
                        cout << "Estatura: " << Alumnos[posicion].estatura << endl;
                        if(Alumnos[posicion].activo)
                            {
                                cout << "El alumno se encuentra activo" << endl;
                            }
                        else
                            {
                                cout << "El alumno no encuentra activo" << endl;
                            }
                        cout << endl;
                    break;
                    case 4:
                        cout << "Dame la edad" << endl;
                        cin >> edad;
                        cin.get();
                        Alumnos[posicion].edad = edad;
                        cout << "Ahora los datos son" << endl;
                        cout << "Datos del alumno " << posicion << endl;
                        cout << "Nombre: " <<  Alumnos[posicion].nombre << endl;
                        cout << "Apellido: " << Alumnos[posicion].apellido << endl;
                        cout << "Edad: " << Alumnos[posicion].edad << endl;
                        cout << "Estatura: " << Alumnos[posicion].estatura << endl;
                        if(Alumnos[posicion].activo)
                            {
                                cout << "El alumno se encuentra activo" << endl;
                            }
                        else
                            {
                                cout << "El alumno no encuentra activo" << endl;
                            }
                        cout << endl;
                    break;
                    case 5:
                        cout << "Dame la estatura" << endl;
                        cin >> estatura;
                        cin.get();
                        Alumnos[posicion].estatura = estatura;
                        cout << "Ahora los datos son" << endl;
                        cout << "Datos del alumno " << posicion << endl;
                        cout << "Nombre: " <<  Alumnos[posicion].nombre << endl;
                        cout << "Apellido: " << Alumnos[posicion].apellido << endl;
                        cout << "Edad: " << Alumnos[posicion].edad << endl;
                        cout << "Estatura: " << Alumnos[posicion].estatura << endl;
                        if(Alumnos[posicion].activo)
                            {
                                cout << "El alumno se encuentra activo" << endl;
                            }
                        else
                            {
                                cout << "El alumno no encuentra activo" << endl;
                            }
                        cout << endl;
                    break;
                    case 6:
                        cout << "El alumno esta activo? (S/N)" << endl;
                        cin >> activo;
                        if((activo=='s')||(activo=='S'))
                            {
                                Alumnos[posicion].activo=true;
                            }
                        else
                            {
                                Alumnos[posicion].activo=false;
                            }
                        cout << "Ahora los datos son" << endl;
                        cout << "Datos del alumno " << posicion << endl;
                        cout << "Nombre: " <<  Alumnos[posicion].nombre << endl;
                        cout << "Apellido: " << Alumnos[posicion].apellido << endl;
                        cout << "Edad: " << Alumnos[posicion].edad << endl;
                        cout << "Estatura: " << Alumnos[posicion].estatura << endl;
                        if(Alumnos[posicion].activo)
                            {
                                cout << "El alumno se encuentra activo" << endl;
                            }
                        else
                            {
                                cout << "El alumno no encuentra activo" << endl;
                            }
                        cout << endl;
                    cin.get();
                    break;
                    default:
                        cout << "Opcion no valida" << endl;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                    {
                        cout << "Posicion inexistente" << endl;
                    }
                cin.get();
        }
        else
            {
                cout << "El arreglo no contiene valores" << endl;
            }
break;

}
}while(opc!=0);
}
```

Me gustaría saber la causa de este problema y como solucionarlo, cualquier otra recomendación ajena a mi pregunta es bienvenida. De antemano, gracias.

Comment: ¿A mi me gustaría saber cual es el problema?

Comment: Cuando sale el texto que pregunta nombre o apellido y se pide la entrada del mismo el programa lo ignora, es decir pregunta pero no espera que el usuario ingrese el dato. Me disculpo por no haber sido del todo clara.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se presenta cuando has leido antes con `cin>>variable`

**¿como corregirlo?**

poniendo `cin.ignore();` antes de leer con `getline`, tu codigo quedaria:

```
cin.ignore(); //despues de leer con cualquier cin>>

cout << "Dame el nombre" << endl;
getline(cin,nombre);
cout << "Dame el apellido" << endl;
getline(cin,apellido);
```

Comment: Te faltaría explicar **por qué** `ignore` soluciona el problema.