# Porque se salta la linea -- cout << "Matricula: "; cin.getline(alumnos[i].matricula, 15); ---- y no me pide la matricula?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

struct alumnos {
    char matricula[15];
    double calificaciones;
}alumnos[35];


int main(){
    int n_alumnos; char resp; double prom_alumnos[35];
    do {
        cout << "Cuantos # numeros de alumnos desea ingresar: "; cin >> n_alumnos;
        for( int i = 0; i < n_alumnos; i++) {
            cout << "Matricula: "; cin.getline(alumnos[i].matricula, 15);
            for( int j = 0, x = 1; j < 5; j++, x++) {
                cout << "\n\tCalificacion " << x << ": "; cin >> alumnos[j].calificaciones;
                prom_alumnos[i] += alumnos[j].calificaciones;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n_alumnos; i++ ) {
            cout << "\n------------------";
            cout << "\nMatricula: " << alumnos[i].matricula;
            cout << "\nPromedio: "<<  prom_alumnos[i]/5;
        }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomando ya una respuesta anterior q ya habia dado en [Entrada de datos mediante std::getline...](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/120247/entrada-de-datos-mediante-stdgetline-no-espera-a-que-el-usuario-ingrese-la-cad/120259#120259)

El error se presenta cuando has leido antes con `cin >> variable`

**¿como corregirlo?**

poniendo `cin.ignore();` antes de leer con `getline`, tu codigo quedaria:

```
cin.ignore(); //despues de leer con cualquier cin >> variable

cout << "Digita tal cosa" << endl;
getline(cin,nombre);
cout << "Digita otra cosa" << endl;
getline(cin,apellido);
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto sucede porque el buffer de lectura está lleno con el caracter `\n` correspondiente a quiebre de línea. Entonces, al hacer la segunda lectura, el `cin` lee el `\n` que está en el buffer e interpreta eso como la entrada.